# Swing graphics in multithreaded program

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I'm coding a game; something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBrEE.png

I have a class named Canvas which extends JLabel and in overriden `paintComponent()`, put an image of gridlines as background, then paint the player and obstacles (walls).

By using `createGraphics()` , I get a Graphics2D object. I need this to paint weapons and bullets from their classes, too. (As you see, there are several weapons that shoot bullets in specific time intervals.)

For implementing all these, using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` I paint the gridlines, player and walls in Canvas class. I thought of creating a thread per weapon and one per bullet; I know, it's an overkill but since I'm new to multithreading I have no other ideas!

And another problem is with Graphics2D object: I need to share this object between threads so I thought of using `final` keyword; but it's not possible because the value of Graphics2D object will be determined in `paintComponent()`.

Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use multi-threaded rendering threads ever (well, in 99% of the cases at least). Most graphics programs keep the full scene state in some object tree that only one thread renders every so often (1/60th of a second). The rendering thread goes through each object in the render tree and invoke .paint or whatever else will get the object to be drawn. Rinse and repeat and you're done.

Comment: So I must do all the painting in one thread and there will be no need to pass Graphics2D obejct anymore; Great! Thanks! but what if some objects needed to be shared whithin threads and making them final isn't possible?

Comment: What kind of sharing do you need? If you're using true OOP, you most likely need to get your objects in better shape.